# resolve the dependence conflict between root module and home module when using pip install

Tags: python, pip

I want to use `pip` to install `PyTables` at home directory, which needs `Cython` 0.13 or greater to compile. Both `pip` and `Cython` are installed by root at `/usr/local/packages/Python/`, but the Cython version is **too old**.

So I installed the latest version of `Cython` by using
`pip install Cython --user`. `Cython` is installed successfully at `/home/$USER/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython`.

When I type `pip install tables --user`, it is still referring to the old version of `Cython`. How can I tell `pip` to use the new version?

Comment: Perhaps export PYTHONPATH=/home/$USER/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ before running pip to give your local directory higher priority on the path list? There's probably a cleaner way of doing this on a system wide level but it may 'just work' and you can move on.